# $F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)*p^k*I_{[1/k^2,\infty]} (x) $. Calculate $F([0,\frac{1}{5}])$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $$F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)*p^k*I_{[1/k^2,\infty]} (x)  $$ where $I$ is an indicator function.

I have to find the probability $P(A)$ where $A=[0,\frac{1}{5}]$

So I started with:

$$F([0,\frac{1}{5}]) = F(\frac{1}{5}) - F(0 -)      $$
where $F(0 -)$ denotes the left $\lim$ of $F(0)$.
Hence,

$$ F(\frac{1}{5}) - F(0 -)   = \sum_{k=4}^\infty (1-p)p^k - \lim_{y \uparrow0}F(y)$$.

But then I am stuck and don't know how to go on. Could anybody provide me with some insides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there; I'll give you two hints:

- For any $y < 0$ and $k > 0$, we have that $I_{[1/k^2,\infty]}(y) = 0$. What does this mean about $F(y)$, and thus about $F(0-)$?
- $\sum\limits_{k = 4}^\infty (1 - p)p^k$ is a geometric series in disguise.  Try factoring out $1 - p$ and re-indexing to use the equality $\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty x^j = \frac{1}{1 - x}$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Since I will always narrow 0 from below so by any $y < 0$ will lead to an $k>0$ as you stated my $y$ will never be in the intervall where my indicator function takes a another value than 0. Hence, this therm is just zero.

Comment: For the geometric series in disguise I set $j=k-4$ then my sum is $(1-p) \sum_{j=0}^\infty p^{j+4}$ and I proceed by $p^4*(1-p)\sum_{j=0}^\infty p^{j}$ and thus $p^4$ for $|x|<1$

Hence, $F([0,\frac{1}{5}]) = p^4$.


Is this right? Thank you very much :)

Comment: It all looks good to me!

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot :)
only thing I wondered is why $k$ starts from 0 since the intervall is $\frac{1}{k^2}$ - this would cause trouble wouldn't it?